# Using Spring Boot TestRestTemplate relative path forces JSON conversion

Tags: java, rest, testing, spring-boot

According to the Spring Boot [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4):

> Note that `TestRestTemplate` is now available as bean whenever
>   `@SpringBootTest` is used. It’s pre-configured to resolve relative paths
>   to `http://localhost:${local.server.port}`. We could have also used the
>   `@LocalServerPort` annotation to inject the actual port that the server
>   is running on into a test field.

I have a RESTFul application that returns XML data. The POM file contains `jackson-dataformat-xml` In the test class, I have the following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class XMLDataTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    ...
    ResponseEntity<List<City>> cities = restTemplate.exchange(appPath,
        HttpMethod.GET, null, paramType);

    assertThat(cities.getBody()).hasSize(8);
    assertThat(cities.getBody()).contains(this.c1, this.c2, this.c3);
```

If the `appPath` equals to the full URL, such as `http://localhost:9234/myapp/cities`, then the test runs OK. If `appPath` equals to a relative path, `/myapp/cities`, I get a JSON exception. It looks like relative paths force JSON conversion.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4628a02b; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:338)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2938)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:924)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:908)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:662)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.exchange(TestRestTemplate.java:812)
    at com.zetcode.test.RestControllerTest.allCitiesTest(RestControllerTest.java:51)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Added the exception. I thought it is a configuration issue.

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the exact **and complete** stack trace of the exception.

Comment: OK, added the complete stack trace.

Comment: Your API (of which we don't have the source code) does return JSON (probably because the request specifies it accepts JSON as response type), but it returns a JSON object, and you expect a JSON array (i.e. a List<City>).

Comment: Spring Boot figures out the  message converter from the POM file. The application returns XML, as expected. Even the tests run OK if I use the full path. They fail if a relative path is used. Therefore I guess this is some Spring Boot automagic configuration issue.

Comment: It's unlikely that it returns XML, since Spring tries to deserialize it with a JSON mapper, and the JSON mapper finds `{` as the first character of the response, which doesn't look like XML. What happens when you pass String.class as response type, and print the string?

Comment: Hmm, in both cases it is JSON data. Thanks to the string printing I found that relative paths should *not include* the context path. So both absolute and relative paths work and return JSON; the only thing remaining is why Spring does not return XML in test environment.

Comment: Passing a RequestEntity which sets the Accept header to XML should force Spring to choose XML as its response type

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by using the `HttpEntity` with the content type set to XML and using this entity in the exchange method. Why don't you create an answer with something like *you need to specify the entity with content type set to XML* and I will accept it and provide code snippet and additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API returns a JSON object, and you expect a JSON array, hence the exception. To make it return XML, you need to specify the Accept header of your request.

Useful trick: when debugging such problems, use String.class as the expected response type, and print the result.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);

ResponseEntity<List<City>> cities = restTemplate.exchange(appPath,
           HttpMethod.GET, entity, paramType);
```